# Where is the exact location of the Temples in Jerusalem?

Tags: history, beis-hamikdash, location

I have heard different theories where the 2 Temples were located. Some say it was on or near the Dome of the Rock. Others say it was farther south, even possibly on Mt. Ophel between the al-Aqsa Mosque and Ir David, and the Dome of the Rock is really in middle of a former Herodian/Roman fortress (Antonia Fortress) which may have originally been built by the Hasmonean Kings.

Many Jews are under the impression that it was over the Rock, and the ['Sanhedrin'](http://www.thesanhedrin.org/en/index.php?title=Psak_5765_Shevat_30) ruled this way.

Where exactly was the Beit Hamikdash located?

Comment: Interesting question EvS. I remember reading on this topic several years ago, but I cannot find the source(s) at  this time. If I recall correctly, there is evidence that the ancient temples are not literally under the mosques occupying what is called the Temple Mount. Access to Temple's Inner Sanctuary, namely Holy of Holies, was limited to the Kohen performing service. But that area was relatively small so I believe the assumption is that if Orthodoxy considers the Temple Mount to be off-limits, it is only because the exact location cannot be identified. I remember a Talmudic teaching.....

Comment: .......that stipulates that the Third Temple must be built on the same footprint as the previous Temple's with further qualification: the Holy of Hollies cannot be restored over a site that was used for pagan worship.

Comment: @JJLL I'm pretty sure everything you just said is false.

Comment: Uh, not everything @DoubleAA. According to this http://www.jcpa.org/jpsr/s99-yc.htm. Rabbi Ovadia Joseph said the precise location of the Temple was not known so Jews were not permitted to enter the area where the mosques stand. It also says that Rabbi Goren's  research led to his belief that the Holy of Holies was not where the Dome of the Rock stands today, thus permitting Jews entry. By the way. if everything I said or implied is false, then the Holy of Holies took up more space than 15% of the Temple claimed by many, the Third Temple could be of different dimensions  since it does not....

Comment: ...have to fit in the same footprint.and the Holy of Holies may be reconstructed over a site used for pagan worship.  Let me do some research and I will try to get additional sources.

Comment: @JJLL You said "Access to...Holy of Holies, was limited to the Kohen performing service. But that area was relatively small so I believe the assumption is that if Orthodoxy considers the Temple Mount to be off-limits, it is only because the exact location cannot be identified." When actually, even the Temple's outer courtyard had restrictions which can't be met today and it is doubt about that which prohibits entry to [parts of] the Mount. And you're right now that the third Temple can be different dimensions and that the Holy of Holies may be reconstructed over a site used for pagan worship.

Comment: Yes, @DoubleAA, but that overlooks the fact that Rabbi Goren warned to blow up the Dome of the Rock. If he thought it was okay to do that..... Of course the rabbi was persuaded to change his view..... This leads us to Maimonides who I almost certain suggested that the Third Temple should and can be built prior to the Messianic Age.     My conclusion DAA, there is no absolute correct answer.

Comment: @JJLL What does his wanting to blow up the Dome have to do with anything? I don't know where you are going with this.

Comment: Come on DAA. If you can blow up Dome of the Rock, you most certainly can walk on/over it.

Comment: @JJLL ??? I don't follow how those are connected.

Comment: Rather interesting info,pics, video's can be found at the following site: http://realtemplemount.com

Comment: @DoubleAA, I suspect that JJLL assumes that to blow up the Dome (something which I am explicitly saying that I don't condone) one would have to enter the building itself. Of course, this is not the case.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Even so, it would probably be permitted [qua Tumah] to enter to do that, because Tumah Hutrah BeTzibbur to build the Temple.

Comment: Am I understanding you correctly @DoubleAA that when the Third Temple is built, Jews would be able to walk everywhere and anywhere on the Temple Mount due to construction purposes? I never quite thought of that. I was lead to believe that God was going to build the Third Temple himself. I suppose that idea is not universally believed.

Comment: @JJLL Whether or not God will build the third temple Himself, it is certainly not only permitted but required to build as much as necessary to ensure time sensitive offerings can be brought, even if that means pushing aside restrictions related to impurity. (It's also possible that when the third temple is built, the Jewish people will have found a way to become fully pure again and will do it themselves in a state of purity.) For more about who will build it see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65130/759

Comment: @DoubleAA. Not your fault, but this is where I get lost. Am I understanding correctly that there are specific circumstances that Jews MAY walk upon any part of the Temple Mount if the purpose is to rebuild as much or as little  of the Temple as possible? Are there any other circumstances that a Jew may enter?

Comment: @JJLL Yes. See Eruvin 105a. (I'm simplifying things here a bit, but there's definitely room to talk about people entering when impure for certain things.)

Answer (score 1):

One of the current summaries of this argument can be found at http://www.templemount.org/theories.html, but I don't think that is authoritative. This link will take you to the TempleMount.org web site page entitled "On the Location of the First and Second Temples in Jerusalem." This site describes three theories of the Temple's location on the Temple Mount with some references to articles in the Biblical Archaeological Review.

Another is http://templemountfaithful.org/articles/temple-location.php. This link will take you to the Temple Mount Faithful site page called "The Location of the Temple and the Holy of Holies on the Temple Mount." This site also describes the three theories of the Temple's location, but does so from a more personal reporting style.

Comment: See http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2188

Comment: Allyn, please summarise these links, per @msh210's critique

Comment: A bit hard to take the Temple Mount Faithful article seriously when it states the following about Rabbe'inu HaRaMBa"M: *"The greatest Jewish rabbi of the exile, the Rambam (Moses ben Maimon), who made a pilgrimage to the Temple Mount in 1165 CE, wrote that **he stood and prayed in the house of prayer, the Dome of the Rock, in** the place which he called, **Kodesh Hakodeshim - the Holy of Holies"***.

Answer (score 0):

- Martin, Ernest L. 2000. [*The temples that Jerusalem forgot*](https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/45673340). Portland, OR: ASK Publications.

considers that the Western/Wailing Wall was part of a Roman fortress called Fort Antonia and not the Temple.

Also, Josephus wrote in his *The Jewish Wars* that the Romans completely destroyed the Second Temple in 70 AD, leveling it to the ground.

Comment: The Western Wall is part of the retaining walls of the Temple Mount. As such, it is not part of the Temple proper. Furthermore, the retaining walls could not have been destroyed, as Hadrianus attempted to build a Roman temple on that site c. 130-135 CE, causing the Bar Kochba rebellion.