# Will the Dome Of The Rock Be Obliterated When Moshiach Comes?

Tags: messiah, beis-hamikdash

I heard the Dome of the Rock was built on the site where the Holy of Holies was, and that also it is on the site where the Third Temple will descend from heaven to earth. So will the Dome of the Rock be obliterated when Moshiach comes?

Comment: If it is on the place of the Bais Hamikdash, where only the Kohanim can enter, then it would have to be demolished. In any case no non-Jews can enter that area.

Comment: @sabbahillel Why can't it exist in the Bais Hamikdash?

Comment: @doubleAA Because you can't have anything there that is not part of the plan.

Comment: @HaLeiVi Oh? How do you know that? Which plan?

Comment: @DoubleAA [עירובין קד](http://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.104a.15)

Comment: @HaLeiVi Isn't that talking about the Mizbeach? The rest of the place doesn't have fixed dimensions. Look how much it differed the second time around. IAE that talks about plans given to David, which are not the same as the third temple, the full plans of which we don't yet have.

Comment: @DoubleAA in [דה"י](http://www.sefaria.org/I_Chronicles.28.11?with=all) it's being applied to the אולם as well. The third has its own Nevua.

Comment: @DoubleAA *"Why can't it exist in the Bais Hamikdash?"* Because it is a mosque. If it were to be a place where goyim would come to worship Hashem it would have to be moved at least.

Comment: @sabbahillel How do you know that? What does a mosque have to do with anything? (note the Dome of the Rock is not a mosque)

Comment: @DoubleAA OK I thought it was the place were they pray on the Har Habayis. What do they do there? I suppose that the inside could be gutted and rebuilt. However, if the third Bais Hamikdash descends from shamayim would it not destroy whatever was there when it came down?

Comment: @sabbahillel Muslim prayers up there happen in the Al-Aqsa Mosque (gray dome, off to the south). I don't think we can claim to know what the physics of a building descending from heaven will be like.

Comment: @sabbahillel Not to mention that not everyone believes it will descend intact from heaven. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/65130/4940

Comment: @magicker72 Those who believe that it will be built bderech hateva would seem to imply that the dome of the rock would have to be totally rebuilt (if not torn down) as well.

Comment: @sabbahillel All of DoubleAA's arguments above apply equally well to a man-made construction.  We don't even need to claim ignorance of the physics of pre-fab buildings: in theory, we know how to build around something.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be knocked down if it's in the way?  It has no *kedusha*; it's just an artifact from a false religion.  Why would the moshiach, or God, care about that?

Comment: @MonicaCellio They care about Pikuach Nefesh and hence (depending on circumstances) about trying to rebuild the Temple without offending the local Muslim population.

Comment: Why all the unjustified downvotes? Seems like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score -1):

The Rambam at the end of melachim umilchamoseihem says that when Moshiach comes all the muslims and notzrim will realize that their ancetors have been teaching them lies and falsities, and will realize the error of their ways -- and he also says that Moshaich will gather all of th other nations under the one Hashem + Torah etc., so its clar there will be no other religions, from the Rambam, hilchos melach hamashiach (end of melachim umilchamoseihem) -- see there for details, but its all in there.

Also Rashi says in Sukkah that the 3rd temple will descend from shamayim to its original place, so obviously we will also need to make room for the 3rd temple.

So 1) there wil be no other religions besides for the One True Hashem and his Torah AKA Judaism + Noahidism (***SEE RAMBAM*** above for sources on that), so obviously there will not only be no more need for it, but it will be a stumbling block for the masses, and everyone will know its not true etc.

Comment: Why would it be a stumbling block if everyone knows it's not true?

Comment: @DoubleAA did you read the rambam? If so you wouldnt be asking that

Comment: Did you write a clear and understable answer? If so I wouldn't be asking that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Yes I did -- do you really think that muslims will still xist when moshiach comes?? What question is there?

Comment: You keep saying that things other people don't know are obviously so to you. That doesn't help anyone else. That's not how communication works. We don't know you that we should trust you.

Comment: @DoubleAA If any1 reads even one word of the Rambam, alll of their questions wil be answered. If they are too lazy to do that, thats not my issue

Comment: What even is an issue

Answer (score -5):

According to our sources Islam will become obsolete because Islam was based on false prophecy as explained [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17729/1857).

Hence there will be no need for it as nobody will be Muslim. The only use would be as a museum, and there's no reason to think that will be the case, especially since this will be prime real estate near or on the Third Temple area.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, which clarified how this answers the question. So you think every building in the world will be destroyed unless we have a known use for it? Would you (nowadays) destroy the house of someone who dies, assuming his heirs have homes already?

Comment: @msh210 and you dont think theres a difference between a building on the temple mount and one in china?

Comment: lots of downvotes but no good explanation why this is not a perfectly valid answer. perhaps not PC?

Comment: @ray PC has nothing to do with it (even if telling yourself that allows you to dismiss legitimate criticism). 3 people commented to explain what the problem they had was. The main issue IMO with this answer is it fails to support it's implied claim that when the Temple is rebuilt nobody will be Muslim. In any event, what will happen then is just your speculation anyway.

Comment: (re your comment addressed to me) You haven't explained any such difference in your answer post. Without that in there, it's a very weak answer.

Comment: @msh210 i fail to see why this is a weak answer. please explain. thanks

Comment: sounds like @Monica Cellio 's comment http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69594/will-the-dome-of-the-rock-be-obliterated-when-moshiach-comes#comment199433_69594 in different words