# What will happen to all other religions places of worship and scripture when moshiach comes

Tags: sources-mekorot, avodah-zarah, messiah

Does it say anywhere in Jewish scripture what will happen to the places of worship and religious scripture of all the other religions of the world when moshiach comes?

Answer (score 1):

I will answer this question with sources besides for Tanach. If you would prefer different sources, please clarify.

The Talmud (Megillah 6b) expounds the verse in [Zechariah (9:7)](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2309.htm):

> וַהֲסִרֹתִי דָמָיו מִפִּיו, וְשִׁקֻּצָיו מִבֵּין שִׁנָּיו, וְנִשְׁאַר גַּם-הוּא, לֵאלֹהֵינוּ; וְהָיָה כְּאַלֻּף בִּיהוּדָה, וְעֶקְרוֹן כִּיבוּסִי

"And I will take away his blood out of his mouth, and his detestable things from between his teeth, and he also shall be a remnant for our God; and he shall be as a chief in Judah, and Ekron as a Jebusite." (Trans. Mechon Mamre).

The Talmud interprets the verse as follows:

> והיה כאלף ביהודה ועקרון כיבוסי - אלו תראטריות וקרקסיות שבאדום שעתידין שרי יהודה ללמד בהן תורה ברבים

'And he shall be as a chief in Judah, and Ekron as a Jebusite'; these are the theaters and circuses in Edom in which princes of Judah are fated to publicly teach Torah.

[Tosafot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tosafot) there comment:

> טראטריות וקרקסיאות - י"מ בתי עבודת כוכבים ומכנה אותן טרטאכ' לשון חרפה וקרקסיאות רוצה לומר בית הכסא בלשון ערב וקשה לומר שאותן מקומות מטונפות יכול ללמוד שם תורה אלא ודאי לשממה יהא במהרה בימינו ורוצה לומר בתים שמתאספים שם לוועד של עובדי עבודת כוכבים.

Some understand "theaters and circuses" to refer to places of non-monotheistic worship...However, it is difficult to suggest that those places will be used for Torah study. Rather, Tosafot opine, such places will be destroyed, and the Talmud refers to mere gathering places (the seemingly correct translation of circuses and theaters).

---

See also this very related question: [Will The Dome Of The Rock Be Obliterated When Moshiach Comes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/69594/will-the-dome-of-the-rock-be-obliterated-when-moshiach-comes?rq=1)

Comment: Cat got your tongues commentless downvoters? Is it Zechariah, the Talmud, or the Tosafot that you object to?

Answer (score 0):

"O LORD, my strength, and my fortress, and my refuge in the day of affliction, the nations shall come unto you from the ends of the earth, and shall say, Surely our fathers have inherited lies, vanity, and worthless things that did them no good" Jeremiah 16:19

Comment: So what will happen with their places of worship?

Comment: @mevaqesh like other worthless things